# Can アジアンビューティー be negative?

Tags: meaning, manga

In a [scene from a manga](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Riiyh.png) classmates are talking about an arrogant pretty girl who's only popular with boys. One of the girls says:「これからアジアンビューティーって呼ぼーよ」.

Is that supposed to sound negative? How so? My first thought was that it's some slang for a prostitute or an "easy girl" but I haven't been able to confirm this. On the internet I found conflicting opinions, so I'm not sure what to think. Is this one of these tricky terms that a foreigner probably just shouldn't use?

Comment: This might be something where you'd find out the most probable meaning by polling the target demographic for the work, else, ask the author.

Comment: OK, I just found out that this is related to her playing 白雪姫, so this question probably can be removed as useless. Unless there is still something interesting to say about the nuances of アジアンビューティー?

Comment: It's only negative because it's being used sarcastically. If originally written in English, they could have use Miss Universe, for example, to get the sarcasm across. As in, "What do you think you're a beauty pageant queen or something?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't have connotation like you thought, though I'm not sure what the manga means by it. It's just <s>a vague</s> an obscure katakana word and it's not settled down how it's used or what it connotes.

It's vague not because it has many meanings or is complicated but because it's not shared among many speakers and nothing has been decided yet.